# How can i remove a row if any input value of a row contains 0, output can be 0 or 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this

| input-1 | input-2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 0 | 1 |
| 50 | 99 | 0 |
| 0 | 45 | 0 |
| 5 | 9 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

now i want to remove all the row which any input column contains 0, if input is not 0 but output is zero its okay i do not delete that row. After deleting my new dataset looks like this:

| input-1 | input-2 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 99 | 0 |
| 5 | 9 | 1 |

How can i do this in python ??

Comment: `df[df[['input-1', 'input-2']].ne(0).all(1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Use boolean slicing. There are many ways:

specific list of target colums

```
df[df[['input-1', 'input-2']].ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

or, global filter based on name:

```
df[df.filter(like='input').ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

or all columns except "output":

```
df[df.drop(columns='output').ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

output:

```
   input-1  input-2  output
1       50       99       0
3        5        9       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do condition filtering the rows

```
data[~((data['input-1']==0) | (data['input-2']==0))]
```

Comment: Yup changed already

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to query your dataframe using boolean expression.

```
df.query('`input-1` != 0 and `input-2` != 0')

   input-1  input-2  output
1       50       99       0
3        5        9       1
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
m = df['input-1'].ne(0) & df['input-2'].ne(0)
df[m]
```